# Octopus Deploy: Cannot create release for deployment

Tags: octopus-deploy

I am unable to create a release in Octopus Deploy.

When I try to create a release, I run into this error below:

[image]

I can't tell where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to fix it.

All I did was restart the server hosting Octopus Deploy.

After the restart, the create release action started working fine again.